# Show that $D \cong {\rm End}_A(D^n)$ where $D$ is a division algebra and $A\cong M_n(D)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, noncommutative-algebra, division-algebras

Define $A$ to be a finite dimensional simple algebra over a field $k$. $D$ is a $k$-division algebra (not necessarily commutative) such that $A\cong M_n(D)$ for some integer $n$. Let $L$ be a minimal left ideal of $A$. Then $L\cong D^n$.

I want to show that $D\cong {\rm End}_A(D^n)$. Do I do this by mapping the matrix of $f\in {\rm End}_A(D^n)$ to its determinant?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is a natural ring homomorphism $\theta:D\to End(_RV)$ given by right multiplication by elements of $D$. That is:

$\theta(d)=\text{right multiplication map by $d$ on $V$}$,

i.e. $(\theta(d))(v)=v\cdot d$

This is immediately injective since $D$ is a division ring.  So it remains to show that it is surjective. This involves little more than some elementary linear algebra.

Let $f\in End(_RV)$ be some element, and (writing it as acting on the right of column vectors) suppose

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots  \\ 0\end{bmatrix}f=\begin{bmatrix}d \\ \ast \\ \vdots  \\ \ast\end{bmatrix}$$

for some element $d\in D$.

Then

$$
\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots  \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}f=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ a_n & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots  \\ 0\end{bmatrix}f=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots  \\ a_n & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}d \\ \ast \\ \vdots  \\ \ast\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1d \\ a_2d \\ \vdots  \\ a_nd\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}a_1 \\ a_2 \\ \vdots  \\ a_n\end{bmatrix}\theta(d)
$$

This shows that $f=\theta(d)$, proving surjectivity.

---

This is a special case of the [double centralizer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_centralizer_theorem) for Artinian rings.  You can find many versions of the proof online and in textbooks.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** The below is wrong if $D$ is not commutative. Not sure what I was thinking 5.5 years ago, so not sure what the thought process was/whether it's salvagable.

---

Note that 
$$\text{End}_D(D^n)=\text{Mat}_n(D)=A$$

Taking the center on both sides yields

$$Z(\text{End}_D(D^n))\cong D$$

But, the center of $\text{End}_D(D^n)$ is just the matrices which are $\text{Mat}_n(D)$-linear. So, by tracking this through the isomorphism $A\cong \text{Mat}_n(D)$, you see this turns into the statement $Z(\text{End}_D(D^n))\cong \text{End}_A(D^n)$.

Comment: What happens if $D$ is not commutative? Does the argument still work? Also could you explain the sentence following the first isomorphism because I can't understand it? Regards

Comment: This doesn't seem correct:  at the very least it forces $D$ to be commutative by supposing it is isomorphic to the center of a ring...  What's actually needed is some proof of (at least a portion of) the double centralizer theorem.

Comment: @rschwieb Yeah dude, sure. This is like 5.5 years old, so I don't remember the context.

Comment: @AlexYoucis It is indeed a special special case of the double centralizer theorem that I think is valid for a matrix ring over a field, but it’s not enough to handle things if $D$ is noncommutative.   $Z(M_1(\mathbb H))=\mathbb R$, but we want to wind up with $\mathbb H$.

Comment: (Apologies for the late critique out of nowhere: a low rep user recently asked a duplicate saying they throughly there might be an issue here, so that’s what drew my attention. Now their question is linked.)

Comment: @rschwieb No problem dude. Glad it's answered.